# ODE with trigonometric functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse-trigonometric-functions

I'm solving the following ODE:

$$(1 + y^2) = (\arctan(y) - x)\frac{dy}{dx},$$

with $y(x)$ being the unknown function. The Solutions sheet recommends substituting $u(x) = \arctan(y(x))$, so that $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{y^2 + 1}\frac{dy}{dx}$. After making the substitution, the sheet reports the equation becoming

$$1 = (\arctan(y) - x)\frac{1}{y^2 + 1}\frac{dy}{dx}.$$

Why does $1 + y^2$ become $1$ after the substitution? Shouldn't it be $1 + \tan^2(u) = \sec^2(u)$?

Comment: You did write the chain rule down, now also apply it in transforming the formula.

Comment: Sorry I just cannot see the point. If $u = \arctan(y)$, $y = \tan(u)$. So $1 + y^2 = 1 + \tan^2(u) = \sec^2(u)$. There is no differentiation involved in that term, so why should one use the chain rule?

Comment: The  equation 1=.. has nothing to do with the substitution, you see that there is no u in it, it is just the original equation bot sides divided by 1+y^2

Comment: You didn't make the substitution.  Your second formula involves $y$ and $x$, not $u$ and $x$.

Comment: You did write that $\frac{dy}{dt}=(1+y^2)\frac{du}{dt}$. If this is correctly applied, there is nothing remaining that you have to worry about. // The (first) aim is to find a differential equation for $u(t)$.

Comment: Ohhh sorry, now I see. Thank you all for the replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't done the substitution yet. The equation
$$
1 = (\arctan(y) - x) \frac{1}{y^2 + 1} \frac{dy}{dx}
$$
is obtained by dividing the given ODE by the quantity $(y^2 + 1)$. Now, it becomes
$$
1 = (u - x) \frac{du}{dx},
$$
but this is still not in a familiar form. Notice that if you define the shifted variable $v = u - x$, so $u = v + x$, then
$$
\dfrac{du}{dx} = \dfrac{dv}{dx} + 1, 
$$
so
$$
1 = v \biggl( \frac{dv}{dx} + 1 \biggr)
$$
or
$$
v\, \frac{dv}{dx} = 1 - v
$$
which is separable. I trust that you can solve this equation for $v$. Then, you have to substitute back $v \mapsto u \mapsto x$.

Of course, this didn't have to happen in two steps since
$$
v = u - x = \arctan y - x 
$$
could be a single substitution $v = \arctan y - x$, but that's hindsight. The path you take to solving the problem is not necessarily the most efficient, "cleanest" solution, but it helps build your intuition for next time.

Comment: Thanks, @LutzLehmann. Silly oversight on my part. I've corrected it.